Where to obtain replacement wood panels for a door?
I have a damaged wood panel in a door, and from what I understand it is possible to replace the wood panel. However my issue is where to find a replacement panel the right size, with the edges cut to fit as a tongue in the grooves? Do I just need to have it custom cut for this? Ive been googling all day and can't seem to find something I can order online!

bring the door to a woodworking shop

Panel might mean different things.  If the type I know of, thin plywood held on/in by moulding, then a sheet of 4x4 under layment/luan and cut to size should work.  If found online, then it is usually quite expensive.  Picture of the door/panel will help.

Doors are not something serviceable by the average or even experienced DIYer.  That and the fact that there are an endless number of sizes and styles.  So only those with all the tools and decades of experience will try to replace a panel for a door.  Your best bet is to contact a door specialist or experienced craftsman that can make the replacement panel you need and do the replacement.  Or buy a new door.

Typically you're going to have to make it, or else have it custom-made by someone else.
